# Validate no of selected items in Kendo-UI MultiSelect-control

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

The MultiSelect-control is bound to a list of strings and it's required that the user select exactly four items.

How can I validate that with Kendo Validator or ASP.Net Validation?

I have also tried to use the Required annotation on the model property, but only that doesn't work. Neither do the Range-keyword since it only works for numeric fields.

Comment: Is using Javascript an option? You can look at the selected values like this `$("#MultiSelectID").data("kendoMultiSelect").value()`

Comment: Yes, it is. But I don't want to get the selected values because they are already visible in the MultiSelect-control. 
What I want is, if the user has selected fewer than four items and press the form submit button. A message should be shown.

Comment: `$("#MultiSelectID").data("kendoMultiSelect").value().length` will get the number of values selected.

Comment: Great, it works :) Now I just need to figure out how to show the error validation message from the model. I have one at the Required-annotation.